# Down sampling a time series data in dplyr from Postgres DB

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, psql

I am trying to use dplyr for querying data from psql. My data is in the following format.

```
date                  name    value
10-12-2012 10:01:00   var1    100
10-12-2012 10:55:00   var1    200
10-12-2012 11:01:00   var1    150
10-12-2012 11:50:00   var1    100
10-12-2012 12:11:00   var1    50
10-12-2012 12:40:00   var1    150
10-12-2012 10:01:00   var2    10
10-12-2012 10:33:00   var2    20
10-12-2012 11:04:00   var2    15
10-12-2012 11:45:00   var2    25
10-12-2012 12:02:00   var2    10
10-12-2012 12:55:00   var2    8
```

I want to aggregate the data to hourly (or predefined sample time) and want the mean value of the "value" column within that hour.

**Required Output:**

```
date                  name    value
10-12-2012 10:00:00   var1    150
10-12-2012 11:00:00   var1    125
10-12-2012 12:00:00   var1    100
10-12-2012 10:00:00   var2    15
10-12-2012 11:00:00   var2    20
10-12-2012 12:00:00   var2    9
```

I can do this in postgres directly using this query:

```
"SELECT date_trunc('hour', date), name, mean_arr(array_agg(cast(value as double precision))) FROM TABLENAME WHERE name IN ("var1","var2")
```

I would like to know, if we can do the same using dplyr.

I am currently connecting to the database using this command in dplyr:

```
my_db <- rc_postgres(dbname="DBNAME",host="HOST",port="PORT",user="USER",password="PASSWD")
tbl_df <- tbl(my_db, "TABLENAME")
```

The raw query is the following:

```
dataOut <- data.frame(tbl_df%>% select(date,name,value) %>% filter(name %in% c('var1','var2')
```

Note that, I haven't aggregated the data currently, which I want to do.

Let me know if someone has answer.
Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work directly with your SQL table. But here is what I would do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- tbl_df %>%
  separate(date, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ") %>%
  separate(time, into = c("hour", "minute", "seccond"), sep = ":") %>%
  group_by(date, hour, name) %>%
  summarise(mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  collect()

#> df
#Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
#
#        date hour name mean(value)
#1 10-12-2012   10 var1         150
#2 10-12-2012   11 var1         125
#3 10-12-2012   12 var1         100
#4 10-12-2012   10 var2          15
#5 10-12-2012   11 var2          20
#6 10-12-2012   12 var2           9
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd try something like this:

```
tbl_df %>%
  filter(name %in% c('var1','var2')) %>% 
  transmute(date_trunc('hour', date), name, mean_arr(array_agg(as.double(value))))
```

Any functions that dplyr doesn't know how to translate will be passed along as is.

Comment: Hi Hadley, I am getting the following error.                              Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "transmutate".

Comment: I couldnt find help for transmutate in dplyr

Comment: @Pradeep - I think Hadley may have meant `transmute` there.